# How to add text-indent to list item in IE 9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am having a styling issue in IE and can't find something to fix it.

IE 9 does not like :

```
.menu ul li a {
    text-indent: 2.75em;
}
```

and if i try a padding left it throws all my list items off.

Can i add padding to the text only, or is there a preferred pay to add text indent to IE 9?

Thanks in advance.

edit

---

This is how my css looks now, but does not work on IE, my text is right up against the side and my points are only half shown.

```
.menu ul li a {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efeff0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.75em;
    line-height: 2.75em;
    text-indent: 2.75em!important;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.923em;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #878d95;
}
```

Comment: How does IE 9 misbehave? Only IE 9 (not 8, 10, etc)? And what HTML are you using?

Comment: Would absolutely positioning it be out of the question?

Comment: @DavidThomas it just ignores text-indent, i assume 8 would do the same, 10 might work as i think IE 10 and 11 are now using edge.